# android studio device profile

Tags: android-studio, adb, device, screen-resolution

I'm trying to set up ADB on a 1080 x 1920 pixel (a ZTE Blade X Max aka Z983) my display at runtime is cropping right & bottom. Looking for more info on how to define device correctly.

Currently have "Generic Phones and Tablets" definition set up for it.
Where are the definition files and how can I edit (and add) ADB profiles?

Comment: Bottom cropping happens after screen auto-rotate to landscape orientation, portrait display appears to fit...

Comment: In my device I found Settings / Display / Display size.  Was "Default" and changing to "Small" got the runtime APK to fit correctly. The compile does not know Android Display size setting adjustment, so "default" and "large" are only showing a smaller "cropped" view of the whole display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADB not the problem, device runtime display size adjustment needed in code???  Found Settings-Display-Display Size in my Android... "Small" is all the pixels. I had "Default" which reduced the visible area, there was also "Large" with even less viewable.
End result --- ADB is max displayable, or "Small". Using alternate "Device for Preview" in editor for "Default" Android setting of fewer pixels